# Exclude URLs from "Expires"-Headers via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
 [...]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

This are my settings for [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) plus the relevant [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). They work perfectly! But I have a specific URL, that shall not be cached. The regex for that would be `^/?nocache/`. Now that directory (`/nocache/`) does not even physically exist; requests to it - as to every other directory - are handled by the "index.php".

My first thought was to add a `<LocationMatch>` around it, but [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch) sais, it is not allowed in the ".htaccess" context.
A `<FilesMatch>` would be allowed but needs the file to physically exist, I think ((true?)).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RewriteRule` directive in .htaccess:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
 [...]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nocache - [E=NOCACHE:1]

SetEnvIf REDIRECT_NOCACHE 1 NOCACHE=1

# DO NOT cache /nocache/ URIs
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0, proxy-revalidate, no-transform" env=NOCACHE
Header set Pragma "no-cache" env=NOCACHE
```

Comment: Does not work, it never matches. To be unambigous: the regex `.*no-cache.*` does not match the received response headers if `http://domain.tld/nocache/test` is requested but `.*Expires:[^\n]+GMT.*` does. Please keep in mind, that I do not have a real directory "/nocache/" anywere. It is part of the URL but not depicted on the server, in fact the "index.php" responds.

Comment: Please add a `SetEnvIf REDIRECT_NOCACHE 1 NOCACHE=1` and change `[E=NOCACHE]` to `[E=NOCACHE:1]`, then I will accept your answer :)

Comment: ok I have done that. We can also do `SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/nocache NOCACHE=1` and skip `RewriteRule` completely.